# How do you instantiate smart pointer class members?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, member, move-semantics

I've been doing some really dodgy smart pointer programming lately because I've never really understood move constructors, move assignments etc. because the examples given on places like MSDN are really convoluted for me. By dodgy, I mean literally changing doing things like (lvalue + 0) to make rvalues.

Here's an example (I'm bad at thinking up scenarios that aren't esoteric):

```
class Person {
public:
    Person(int age) {
        age_ = age;
    }

private:
    int age_;
};

class Life {
public:
    Life(int age) {
        person_ = std::make_unique<Person>(age);
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Person> person_;
};
```

The age part has to be an rvalue, what would be the proper way to do make this an rvalue? I've read about move constructors but they seem to be passing and rvalue reference of the object itself?

EDIT: Also, is it possible to initialize smart pointer members from the class constructor's member initializer list?

Comment: I would stay away from MSDN for anything not specifically related to Microsoft products.  For C++ information, you should make [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) your first port of call.

Comment: "*The age part has to be an rvalue*" Which `age` part? Well, that's a trick question, since *none of them* have to be an rvalue. I have no idea where you're getting this from. And if you ever do `(lvalue + 0)` to create an rvalue, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas The IDE I'm using warns me that the age std::make_unique<Person>(age) needs to be an rvalue expression. However, it compiles just fine. http://i.imgur.com/cFSbE4w.png

Comment: What IDE is this? Version etc please.

Comment: @Technik Empire It's the newest version of CLion. I get the error in Qt Creator as well with the same code.

Comment: Then CLion is a piece of garbage that is interpreting assignment to `make_shared` as a move but then enforcing rvalues on the arguments supplied to `make_shared` also, which it should not. The arguments supplied to `make_shared` are to be taken as universal references and forward to `Person` ctor and then the `unique_ptr<Person>` is to be moved. CLion thinks everything on the right hand side of the assignment should be moved. Get a refund and download a real IDE for free.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Interesting. Don't worry, I have a student license for CLion ;) What IDE would you recommend? I use Linux and have used Qt Creator, CodeBlocks, Eclipse CDT etc. but have preferred CLion.

Comment: When on Linux, I've used Eclipse + CDT. Eclipse has a lot of shortcomings on Windows but I've never had a single issue with it like this under Linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103038/discussion-between-technik-empire-and-user3530525).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following, which creates a Person pointer and assign it to the unique_ptr:

```
class Life {
 public:
  Life(int age) : person_(new Person(age)) {}
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @keelar Is there a way to do it without using the member initializer list? Like in the constructor body?

Comment: @user3530525 `std::unique_ptr<T>::reset(new T(...))`

Answer (score 0):

At first if you need a rvalue from a lvalue, the straightforward way is std::move(a), just that, but is important to notice what you are doing with that. You are transforming your reference in lvalue wich means "if you need you could change that because I do not need anymore that values".

But in your cases really do not matter if they are rvalue or lvalue since your int parameter is a pass-by-copy value, this just matter with you have a Person(int& age) or Person(int&& age), what is not your case.

But in this case matters

```
std::vector<int> b = ...
std::vector<int> a = b; //rvalue, means keep safe this data, I still need them 
std::vector<int> a = std::move(b);//lvalue, could be changed
std::vector<int> a = f(); //lvalue, could be changed since is just a temporary data
```